# Changing date format on main page, wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, date-format

This is the php code for date format on my web page

```
 function starkers_posted_on() {
    printf( __( 'Posted on %2$s by %3$s', 'starkers' ),
        'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time datetime="%3$s" pubdate>%4$s</time></a>',
            get_permalink(),
            esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
            get_the_date('Y-m-d'),
            get_the_date()
        ),
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
            sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'starkers' ), get_the_author() ),
            get_the_author()
        )
    );
}
```

it gives this

```
 Posted on <a href="#" title="23:50" rel="bookmark">
       <time datetime="2012-03-31" pubdate="">March 31 2012</time>
       </a> by <a href="#" title="View all posts by me">me</a>
```

What I want is to wrap Month, date, and year separately inside divs like this only on the main page:

```
<div class="month">March</div>
<div class="date">31</div>
<div class="year">2012</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by passing in a format string parameter into the `get_the_date()` function like this:

You could do something like this:

```
sprintf('<div class="month">%s</div>', get_the_date('F'));
sprintf('<div class="date">%s</div>', get_the_date('j'));
sprintf('<div class="year">%s</div>', get_the_date('Y'));
```

**UPDATE**

Or like this in your index.php file (from your themes folder):

```
<div class="month"><?php get_the_date('F'); ?></div>
<div class="date"><?php get_the_date('j'); ?></div>
<div class="year"><?php get_the_date('Y'); ?></div>
```

The format strings use here are as follows:

- `F` = Month (as a word)
- `j` = Day of the month (number)
- `Y` = Year (as 4 digits)

[Check the docs here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time).

Comment: I dont know well php could you tell me where I should put it?

Comment: @FoxKllD it depends where you want the divs to be rendered. You say its on your homepage, so find the `index.php` file in your theme and put the code that i've added to my answer somewhere in that file (depending on where you want it).